# Is this the correct understanding of null sets and measures (w.r.t. prob densities)?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all continuous probability densities.

I want a sub-family $\mathcal{F}_0$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that has a particular property (irrelavant here) such that every null-set of $\mathcal{F}_0$ is a null-set of $\mathcal{F}$.

It turns out that the location family of densities $Cauchy(\theta,1)$ has this particular property I'm after. All that remains is to verify the null-set condition.

Now, this family of Cauchy densities has support on the entire real line. So, is it correct to say this implies every null set of $\mathcal{F}_0$ is a null set of $\mathcal{F}$? Since the family of densities in $\mathcal{F}$ is restricted to having support only on the real line? So it's impossible to construct a null set of $\mathcal{F}_0$ that is not also a null set of $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: That depends on your notion of support. In terms of the support of the density as a continuous function, you are right. Every strictly positive density has the same null sets. But if the density only delivers full support in the measure theoretic sense (the smallest closed set of measure 1 is the entire real line), it this need not be the case.

Comment: So if I am defining null set with respect to the distribution functions associated with each density, it is correct then? ie. $P(A) = \int_A p(x) = 0$ meaning $A$ is a null set for densitiy $p$? Sorry, I am not good with measure theory so even the simple stuff trips me up

Comment: For Cauchy or any strictly positive density yes. If $p$ is a strictly positive measurable function, then $\int_A p=0$ if and only if $A$ has measure zero.